# Table converted into divs

Tags: html, css

In order to optimize my content i've read that tables are'nt good practice and therefor i'm trying to convert a table into divs. However i'm struggling to convert it into divs. How can the following table be converted into divs?

```css
.match-table {

    height: 38px;
    
}

.match-table tr {

      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid  #e5e5e5;
}



.match-icon {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;

}

.match-time {
    width:8%;
    height: 38px;
    text-align: right;
}

.match-home {
    text-align: right;

    width: 32%;
}
.match-score{
    text-align: center;

    width: 20%;
}
.match-away{
    text-align: left;

    width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<table class="match-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="margin-tr">
<td class="match-icon">PBL</td>
<td class="match-home">Gambit</td>
<td class="match-score">2-3</td>
<td class="match-away">TSM</td>
<td class="match-time">22:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="margin-tr">
<td class="match-icon">PBL</td>
<td class="match-home">Gambit</td>
<td class="match-score">2-3</td>
<td class="match-away">TSM</td>
<td class="match-time">22:00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using `<table>` is not good practice if it is solely for layout reasons. It is perfectly appropriate for tabulated data, though :) and it seems like you *are* using tabulated data, so `<table>`, for once, is actually semantically correct in your case.

Comment: It's incredible that in 2014/2015 people still have to spell out that using `<table>` for tabular data is, in fact, entirely acceptable.

Comment: Sorry i'm normally not developing front end, so i researched on it and seemed like people wanted to avoid using it due to page ranking reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For data best represented in a table, a `<table>` is just fine.  This appears to be the case with your example, so I'd advise you to simply keep it in a table format unless there is a layout or design component that really indicates a need for a more complicated div-based layout.

Typically, using tables is an inadvisable practice when they're being used (inappropriately) for layout.  For the display of tabular data, they're fine.

Comment: This is quite correct, but does not answer the question at all. If a question is misguided, it should be said as comments, not as answers.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Plan B, Terry and Yesthe Cia, but just in case someone else has the same doubt and would like to convert non-data  table layouts into div layouts, here's how it could be done.

```css
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.match-table {
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10%;
}
.match-table > div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.match-table .match {
    float: left;
}
.match-icon {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}
.match-time {
    width:8%;
    height: 38px;
    text-align: right;
}
.match-home {
    text-align: right;
    width: 32%;
}
.match-score {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}
.match-away {
    text-align: left;
    width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="match-table">
    <div class="margin-tr">
        <div class="match match-icon">PBL</div>
        <div class="match match-home">Gambit</div>
        <div class="match match-score">2-3</div>
        <div class="match match-away">TSM</div>
        <div class="match match-time">22:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="margin-tr">
        <div class="match match-icon">PBL</div>
        <div class="match match-home">Gambit</div>
        <div class="match match-score">2-3</div>
        <div class="match match-away">TSM</div>
        <div class="match match-time">22:00</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might as well use [`display: table / table-row / table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) if you want to mimic a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are still perfect or tabulated data. For what you're trying to represent above it makes no sense to not use tables. Thats what tables are for. They're not deprecated and still in wide use today.

Don't listen to the people who tell you they have no place in modern web design - just dont use them or wider site layout ;)